# Can you identify this climbing plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

In my house there's a strange plant that I see growing for years now. I believe it is a climbing plant. Do you know how is this plant named? Is it poisonous?

Location: Greece

Altitude: 800m. 
[image: The whole plant]

[image: Plant's fruits]

[image: Plant's leaf]

Comment: if you don't get answers here, this question would also be on topic on Gardening: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have any idea what the flowers look like? A picture would be fantastic, but color, size and/or number of petals would also help a great deal.

Comment: we have this all over the place in france. it tends to wilt as the summer goes on, it has annoyingly hairy leaves which are a bit weird. red briony https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Bryonia_dioica_%282144983672%29.jpg they used to put it on the bandages of lepers, you know those who lose fingers and limbs to consumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the fruits, leaves and [tendrils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendril), it looks quite like [*Bryonia dioica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryonia_dioica) (which is toxic). It is almost certainly something from the same family (Cucurbitaceae, which often make such tendrils and usually have similar leaf shapes) and could even be the same genus, [*Bryonia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryonia), which is present in the Mediterranean region (there's even a *cretica* species). Based on images found on the internet, leaf shape seems variable (more or less indented).